# how to ask for admin rights in android?

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

I do not want to launch with root, just as a common Android app, like other. I want to ask the user nicely and after that have the admin access and protection. Kaspersky is able to do it, so others should be able too. 
[image: screenshot]

What are the API calls here?

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with root. You can tell that because the screenshot does not mention "root" anywhere.

Comment: @CommonsWare you have right, didn't know either I can have admin,but not root, altough I should have a Linux somewhere...

Comment: Device admin, in Android terms, has nothing to do with Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using the Device Administration APIs, you can read about it here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Answer (score 2):

You can clone this eclipse project :

https://github.com/pedrolobito/DeviceAdminDemo

It's a fully working Android Device Admin App.